# How to write over a table?

Tags: tables

I would like to make a *hanzi grid* for practicing Chinese characters, like this one: http://www.hanzigrids.com/version/1328584298/example-pdfs/hanzigrids-yingbikaishu.pdf

I am able to make the table with the *arydshln* package, like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c:c|c:c|c:c|c:c|}
  \hline
  & & & & & & & \\
  \hdashline
  & & & & & & & \\
  \hline
  & & & & & & & \\
  \hdashline
  & & & & & & & \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

but how can I write the characters over the table?

Comment: Would [Copybook for calligraphy](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131825/22413) work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is inspired by [qingkuan@bbs.ctex.org](http://bbs.ctex.org/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=77611&pid=455417&fromuid=109739).

When I saw your question yesterday, three possible solutions came into my mind. They are:

- Select a font whose chars has a rice-shaped grid (米字格).
- Use LaTeX tabular to draw these grids, and then fill Chinese chars into them.
- Get the position and size of each Chinese chars, and then, draw the grids with Ti*k*Z.

The first possible solution is direct but lack of portability, and the second one is not a good choice if one wish to make line-breaking automatically (also page-breaking). Hence, the last one seems to be the only choice.

The package `soul` insert things after every possible hyphenation (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6029/38350)), which could help us finding the line-break point. However, the package `soul` is sometimes fragile, since it cannot work well with the package `xeCJK` which is an important Chinese supporting package.

[Qingkuan@bbs.ctex.org](http://bbs.ctex.org/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=77611&pid=455417&fromuid=109739) helped me replenishing the already-off trail.

Testing every chars in `.tex` source file, `xeCJK` is able to figure out if a specific char is a CJK (Chinese, Japanese and Korean) char. Hence, we are now able to get the position of every Chinese char's position.

**Output**

Let's see the output first.

> [image]

**Requirements**

- Encoding: UTF-8
- Engine: XeTeX (start command line with `xelatex`)
- Packages: [`xeCJK`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xecjk) (later than v3.2.8, 2013/12/05), [`ctex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctex)
- Font: Adobe Chinese-simp fonts (click [here](http://ishare.iask.sina.com.cn/download/explain.php?fileid=15105086) to start downloading automatically, these four fonts are free, don't worry about the copyright)

**Code**

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8, adobefonts]{ctexart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin = 2.1cm, papersize = {16cm, 13cm}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\linespread{0.833333}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_@@_grid_box % l means local
\coffin_new:N \l_@@_grid_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_@@_charater_coffin
\int_const:Nn \c_@@_test_char { "4E00 }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_update_grid_box:
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_@@_grid_box
      { \XeTeXuseglyphmetrics = \c_zero \c_@@_test_char }
    \use:x
      {
        \@@_update_grid_box:nnn
          { \dim_use:N \box_wd:N \l_@@_grid_box } % width
          { \dim_use:N \box_ht:N \l_@@_grid_box } % height
          { \dim_use:N \box_dp:N \l_@@_grid_box } % depth
      }
    \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn
      \l_@@_charater_coffin { hc } { vc }
      \l_@@_grid_coffin     { hc } { vc }
      { \c_zero_dim } { \c_zero_dim }
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_@@_grid_box
      {
        \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_@@_charater_coffin
          { H } { l } { \c_zero_dim } { \c_zero_dim }
      }
    \box_set_wd:Nn \l_@@_grid_box { \c_zero_dim }
    \box_set_ht:Nn \l_@@_grid_box { \c_zero_dim }
    \box_set_dp:Nn \l_@@_grid_box { \c_zero_dim }
  }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_update_grid_box:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_@@_grid_box { }
    \box_set_wd:Nn \l_@@_grid_box {#1}
    \box_set_ht:Nn \l_@@_grid_box {#2}
    \box_set_dp:Nn \l_@@_grid_box {#3}
    \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_@@_charater_coffin { \box_use:N \l_@@_grid_box }
    \@@_draw_grid:nn {#1} { (#2) + (#3) }
  }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_draw_grid:nn #1#2
  {
    \use:x
      {
        \@@_draw_grid:nnnn { \dim_eval:n {#1} } { \dim_eval:n {#2} }
          { \dim_eval:n { (#1) / 2 } } { \dim_eval:n { (#2) / 2 } }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_draw_grid:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_@@_grid_coffin
      {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw[help~lines] (0,#4) -- (#1,#4) (#3,0) -- (#3,#2);
          \draw[help~lines,dashed] (0,0) -- (#1,#2) (0,#2) -- (#1,0);
          \draw[help~lines, red, thick] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_grid_CJKsymbol:n
  { \box_use:N \l_@@_grid_box \@@_grid_CJKsymbol:n }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_grid_CJKpunctsymbol:n
  { \box_use:N \l_@@_grid_box \@@_grid_CJKpunctsymbol:n }
\keys_define:nn { @@ }
  {
    format .tl_set:N  = \l_@@_formal_tl ,
    format .initial:n = { \normalfont }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \@@_active_grid:n #1
  {
    \xeCJKsetup{PunctStyle=plain,CJKglue=\allowbreak,AllowBreakBetweenPuncts}
    \keys_set:nn { @@ } {#1}
    \tl_use:N \l_@@_formal_tl
    \@@_update_grid_box:
    \xeCJK_swap_cs:NN \CJKsymbol \@@_grid_CJKsymbol:n
    \xeCJK_swap_cs:NN \CJKpunctsymbol \@@_grid_CJKpunctsymbol:n
    \__xeCJK_add_to_shipout:n
      {
        \xeCJK_swap_cs:NN \CJKsymbol \@@_grid_CJKsymbol:n
        \xeCJK_swap_cs:NN \CJKpunctsymbol \@@_grid_CJKpunctsymbol:n
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \CJKgrid { +O { } +m }
  { \group_begin: \@@_active_grid:n {#1} #2 \relax \group_end: }
\NewDocumentEnvironment { CJKGrid } { +O { } }
  { \@@_active_grid:n {#1} } { \par }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\zihao{0}
\CJKgrid{\kaishu 我\color{gray!20}我我我我我我\color{white}我}

\CJKgrid{\kaishu 喜\color{gray!20}喜喜喜喜喜喜\color{white}喜}

\CJKgrid{\kaishu 歡\color{gray!20}歡歡歡歡歡歡\color{white}歡}

\CJKgrid{\kaishu 寫\color{gray!20}寫寫寫寫寫寫\color{white}寫}

\CJKgrid{\kaishu 漢\color{gray!20}漢漢漢漢漢漢\color{white}漢}

\CJKgrid{\kaishu 字\color{gray!20}字字字字字字\color{white}字}


\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

The Adobe fonts is not really necessary, since they are used here for displaying. One can replace the option `adobefonts` by `nofonts`, and then reset fonts by control sequences provided by `xeCJK` (See its documentation for details).